# Using Bullmq sandboxed job with NX by building files separately

Tags: javascript, node.js, monorepo, nx-workspace, bullmq

I am working on an nx monorepo and it has multiple projects within it. I have been working on server code to complete heavy tasks that may arise separately from the rest of the server process. To achieve this I am using bullmq to queue tasks and parallelize their execution. However, because the tasks I am running are time and CPU-intensive, jobs are frequently stalled. To avoid this I want to run the tasks in a separate sandboxed process. The way to make a sandbox process needs a reference to a .js file that will be generated when the project compiles (if I write the task handler in the handler.ts file I need to reference the handler.js file).

The problem is that nx combines every source file into one when it builds the project. I need a way to force nx to build source files separately so that I can access the compiled task handler file.

I run into a stack overflow answer that suggested writing a custom target for building the specific project within the monorepo. But it was not a solution for me as it has issues when importing code from an external library within the monorepo.

Or if you have any alternative solutions, I am open to suggestions